# ZATS: ZatsException: instance not found, please call init first

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, zk

i'm writing my first zats-test and i'm trying to do it according to the example at  [zkoss](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZATS%20Essentials/Getting%20Started/First%20Mimic%20Test%20Case/TestNG%20Example).

This is my test:

```
public class zatsTest {
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    Zats.init("./src/main/resources/web");
}

@AfterClass
public static void end() {
    Zats.end();
}

@AfterMethod
public void after() {
    Zats.cleanup();
}

@Test
public void testLoginGUI() {
log.info("Testing Login GUI ...");
DesktopAgent deskAgent = Zats.newClient().connect("/login.zul");//<---

ComponentAgent button = deskAgent.query("loginButton");
ComponentAgent tbLogin = deskAgent.query("#login");
ComponentAgent tbPassword = deskAgent.query("#password");

// Successful login
log.info("Testing correct login and password...");
tbLogin.type("root");
tbPassword.type("nysnys");
Assert.assertEquals(deskAgent.query("#login"), "root", "correct login must be 'root' ");
Assert.assertEquals(deskAgent.query("#password"), "password", "correct password must be 'nysnys' ");
button.click();
log.info("Testing Login GUI has been finished.");
}
}
```

I've recieved this:

> org.zkoss.zats.ZatsException: **instance not found, please call init**
>   first     at org.zkoss.zats.mimic.Zats.getInstance(Zats.java:33)  at
>   org.zkoss.zats.mimic.Zats.newClient(Zats.java:61)     at
>   zats_test.zatsTest.testLoginGUI2(zatsTest.java:45)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:821)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:773)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:623)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1185)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1110)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1018)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)

For my internship I have to understand how ZATS work and make a test for Login zk Gui (ZK 8.0 and zats-mimic-ext7 version 1.2.0, Maven project). But I'm a bit puzzled.
I use TestNG.

[maven project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/441Zm.png)

Comment: Are you using TestNG or JUnit?

Comment: As you wrote that you are using TestNG, it seems worth noticing that TestNG does not require the `@BeforeClass` method to be static - only JUnit does that. I haven't used TestNG myself yet, but it could be worth a try to make it non-static or put a logging (or breakpoint) there to see if it's actually called. Otherwise the code seems functional and pretty much how the ZATS class is supposed to be used.

Comment: thank you i have just tried without static but the result the same (

Comment: Did you check if the method actually gets called? You could also try to introduce a variable `ZatsEnvironment env = new DefaultZatsEnvironment("./src/main/webapp/WEB-INF");` and then call the init on that variable instead (newClient then also, of course).

Comment: How do you run the test?

Comment: i think it wasn't called.  DefaultZatsEnvironment i have tried but still - nothing. The project doesn't have WEB-INF at all.

Comment: Does it work when you do `Zats.init()` directly in the `testLoginGUI`method?

Comment: no  the test runs till DesktopAgent deskAgent = Zats.newClient().connect("/login.zul"); than fails...

Comment: Are there any other exceptions? I don't see where this can fail this way, even in source code...

Comment: org.zkoss.zats.ZatsException: instance not found, please call init --- this is the only

Comment: I'm out of clues, sry...

Comment: In any case, thank you for trying... i'll write if i cope with it

Comment: Can you try like here :http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZATS_Essentials/Mimic_Library/Advanced_Usage/Customize_Test_Environment

Answer (score 1):

So, this helped me to solve the problem for my reactor project.

```
            env = new DefaultZatsEnvironment("../ControlCenterPack/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF");
            env.init("../ControlCenterCore/src/main/resources/web");
```